# Why should temples be closed during an eclipse?

Tags: temple, agamas, dharma-shastras, eclipse

Any reference in the Hindu scriptures (Vedas, Agamas, shastras, etc.) on why temples should remain closed during an eclipse (grahana)?

Comment: Good question. As such i feel.there is no.need to close temples. In fact religious and spiritual activities should be e.encouraged that time

Comment: Well, it could be down to custom as well but it would be great to know. I personally think there are good reason for closure due to the upsetting of the light rays on the energy around us - there are researches done on these already.

Comment: What.research ? You mean.this time.is not good for spiritual or religious stuff ?

Comment: We cannot explain everything yet in this world is my personal belief. The university of reading for instance has been conducting researches on climatic changes during eclipses. Other researches have been conducted on animal behavioral changes during phenomenon. The list is available just see any academia listing.

Comment: If you dont have explanation its okay but don't please brand it as a research. Just the point is how its related to worship or spirituality

Comment: Sorry to waste your and my time. A research is a research and the uni running those do not have to justify their findings to prove their point to us as it did not have a religious connotation but factual. The remark to everything cannot be explained was a generic remark over and above the subject in question here. Our forefathers knew gravitational pull and waves but could not explain it...yet there is now a Nobel prize winner on the subject now.

Comment: Research is okay but what if its not relevant to this subject ? It says about climate changes and we.are talking about spiritual activities. Getting the point ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi except Srikalahasti Temple, all other temples are closed because Agama Sastras say so. At least, this is what i hear from Pundits in TV.

Comment: Gods are not bound by natural occurrences, they are consciousness level, beyond space time....the agamas governs temple rituals and rites...there are about 200 agamas for temples and it's presiding deity. 1 temple follow 1 agama...my question is can someone quote from any agama that prohibits closure of temples during eclipses...it's good to educate the community rather then simply saying Hinduism says...